# 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'to_delayed'?

Tags: dask, dask-distributed, dask-dataframe, dask-delayed, dask-ml

I am using randomforest model from scikit learn and BlockwisevottingRegressor from dask.
Code:
[image]

Error:
[image]

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551). Instead please use a [formatted code block](/help/formatting) and make sure to always post all your code and a [full traceback](//realpython.com/python-traceback) when asking about errors. Thanks!

Comment: what's `type(X_train)`? Looks like it's not a dask dataframe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem stems from the lines:

```py
Xs = X.to_delayed()
ys = y.to_delayed()
```

The `.to_delayed()` method is defined for dask DataFrames and dask Arrays, but not for `pandas` or `numpy` objects. It's likely that the labels `X` and `y` are associated with a `pandas` DataFrame.

In the error traceback image, the `AttributeError` suggests that the object is a pandas `DataFrame` (possibly another library's DataFrame, but most likely a pandas one).

Not much more can be derived from the image posted.

Comment: But I am not even passsing X and Y. I am passing X_train and y_train. And I checked their data type. and it showing dask dataframe for X_train and dask array for y_train.

Comment: Hmm, that's what traceback is pointing to, so something might be happening in the train_test_split.